# How is the UDP checksum verified at the receiver when you send FFFFh?

Tags: networking, udp

I'm talking about the special case when the one's complement of the sum results in 0 and we send its 1's complement FFFFh.What does the receiver add in order to make up for this change?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, or maybe you don't understand that the receiver performs the exact same calculation as the sender, so the results would be the same. The receiver would come to the same conclusion that `0x0000` would need to be changed to `0xffff`.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn’t aware that the receiver works like that!